# IE 10 does not load embedded base64 font

Tags: html, internet-explorer, font-face, webfonts

Check out this code:

http://jsbin.com/anecor/1

What it basically does is render two different texts, using two different 'font-family'es

With text # 1, the font data gets loaded along with the document.

With text # 2, the font data gets appended to the head tag 2 seconds after the page loads.

If you try out the code in possibly any modern browser (I've already tried Chrome, Firefox and iOS Safari) it will work and both fonts will have their style set correctly; however, if you run this on IE 10, the second font will fail to render.

No error messages and no clue why it stops working.

Also, I'm pretty sure that (surprisingly) it will work on IE 9, because I was doing most of my tests using that browser; but then I recently upgraded to Windows 8 and only have IE 10 atm, if someone can check it out and tell me it works/fails on IE 9 it would be appreciated.

Any ideas? Workarounds?

Comment: Why would you want to add a style block in this way after the page has already rendered?

Comment: It actually gets called on an AJAX request. The server renders the font data and that's what the page loads. For my particular needs, I'm not able to render that to a file and then serve it in a traditional manner with <link rel...> or <style src...>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. Load the font like this:

```
var css = '@font-face {...}';
var s = document.createElement('style');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
if (s.styleSheet) { // IE
    s.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out this is a bug on IE (and does not work on IE 11 either, so here we have a bug that will stay for a long while).

Also crafted a workaround but it's very complex (however it does work). If someone's interested someday just drop me a message.

Comment: I'd like to know more about your workaround for this, running into this issue as well.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. Please share possible workarounds if possible.